# Microsoft Virtual PC maximum hard disk PC

Tags: disk-space, microsoft-virtual-pc

What is the maximum space that I can allocate on a MS Virtual PC 2007?

Comment: Doesn't Mike's response answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed disks are limited by the host file system limitations, eg. 4GB on FAT32.

Dynamic disks are limited to 2048GB or the host file system limitations.

Source: [MS Virtual Hard Disk Image Format Specification v1.0](http://download.microsoft.com/download/f/f/e/ffef50a5-07dd-4cf8-aaa3-442c0673a029/Virtual%20Hard%20Disk%20Format%20Spec_10_18_06.doc)

And available free space, obviously :)

Comment: And you can have multiple VHDs for a single VM.

Comment: And you can link direct to real disk partitions also.