# Virtual PC dynamic disk - why limited to 130GB?

Tags: hard-drive, virtual-machine, microsoft-virtual-pc

On my Windows 7 machine with XP Mode installed, I created a new VM in Virtual PC. I have a 1TB SATA drive installed in the machine and when I create a dynamic (expanding) disk, it only allows me to create it as a 130GB drive.

If I choose fixed disk size, I can create a 950GB size drive. Any thoughts as to why this is, or is it normal?

According to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/132336/microsoft-virtual-pc-maximum-hard-disk-pc), even dynamic disks should be able to go larger than 130GB.

Answer (score 2):

Virtual PC has a fixed limit of 130GB and there isn't any way to get around it.

It seems to be based around the old pre-48-bit LBA days (around 2002-2003 if I remember right) where OSes & motherboards couldn't address more than 137GB on a hard drive. In those days when drives first started getting bigger than 120gb if you had a really old mobo or OS that didn't support 48bit LBA (windows xp before sp1 or older) you would have to jumper the large drives to only report 137GB.

I'm guessing that Virtual PCs virtual hardware/bios might actually be really old and not support 48bit LBA.

That or Microsoft is just being a punk and put in an artificial limit so businesses would use the HyperV server product.

Comment: My guess would be the latter, VPC is seen as a personal 'tool' rather than a complete application for business use.